# What's the difference between io.Copy and io.CopyBuffer?

Tags: go, io

In the documentation of [io.CopyBuffer](https://pkg.go.dev/io#CopyBuffer) it states:

> CopyBuffer is identical to Copy except that it stages through the
> provided buffer (if one is required) rather than allocating a
> temporary one.

Does that mean that `io.CopyBuffer` will copy first to buffer and then into destination making less calls to source Write?

Comment: CopyBuffer let’s you allocate your own buffer. It is otherwise the same as Copy. If you look at Copy, it just calls CopyBuffer

Comment: What would be the benefit of it? It looks like the io.Copy will have a buffer or 32768(calling copyBuffer with buf nil)

Comment: It let's you choose your own buffer size. `io.Copy` by default uses a 32K buffer. If you know your copy will be large, a larger buffer may be more performant.

Comment: @colm.anseo I guess this goes the other way around as well. If I know my copy is smaller I can use a smaller buffer than 32k thus less memory being allocated for my copy

Comment: In addition to allowing the caller to control the size of the buffer, a caller can use a single  buffer for multiple copy operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CopyBuffer let’s you allocate your own buffer. It is otherwise the same as
Copy. If you look at Copy, it just calls CopyBuffer.

CopyBuffer let's you choose your own buffer size. io.Copy by default uses a 32K
buffer. If you know your copy will be large, a larger buffer may be more
performant. In addition to allowing the caller to control the size of the
buffer, a caller can use a single buffer for multiple copy operations.